# How should I insert data into DB

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to create a user with my custom authentication and getting 500 error while posting data.
I gues I messed something wrong with user model. Because If I trying to return the input from the form it's return succefull but If I'm trying to post data to DB I'm getting 500 error. ps .env is configured correctly.
**User model:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
   
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'password',
    ];

}
```

**Auth Controller:**

```
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Models\User;
    
    class AuthController extends Controller
    {
       
 //Login function
     function register(){
        return view('auth.register');
    }

        //Create user in DB
        function create(Request $request){
    
            //Validate requests
            $request->validate([
                'name'=>'required',
                'password'=>'required'
            ]);
    
             //Insert data into database
             $user = new User;
             $user->name = $request->name;
             $user->password = Hash::make($request->password);
             $save = $user->save();
    
            
        }
    
       
        }
```

**Routes:**

```
**<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;



//Register Route
Route::get('/auth/register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);

Route::post('/auth/create', [AuthController::class, 'create'])->name('auth.create');**
```

Comment: Turn on the debugger and check what's the error!

Comment: We need to know what is the actual error. Set `APP_DEBUG=true` in your `.env` file or look in the logs (`storage/logs/laravel.log`)

Comment: Make APP_DEBUG=true, as your debugger is off

Comment: Your AuthController did not initialized `use Hash;`. This could be case for getting error.

Comment: @ApurvBhavsar that's right. He's not using use Hash, and as the debugger is off as well, so it's not throwing the error

Comment: I recommend using [Laravel authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#authentication-quickstart) it is really powerful and editable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if there are some columns not nullable or can't be empty.

Set `APP_DEBUG=true` at `.env` file you see errors.

If you are using the default user table

```
$table->id();
$table->string('name'); // can't be empty
$table->string('email')->unique(); // can't be empty
$table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
$table->string('password'); // can't be empty
$table->rememberToken();
$table->timestamps();
```

UPDATE:

As [apurv-bhavsar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16509073/apurv-bhavsar) said you must add `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;` before the class

```
...
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash; // <<

class AuthController extends Controller
...
```